# Angular 5 not parsing timestamps correctly from json

Tags: json, angular, datetime, nancy

I have a working (in production) web app (material + angular 5 (5.2.11)). Also I've an API written in .dot core 2 (C#) using Nancy FX and newtonsoft json.

**Problem:**

DB (mariaDB running on Ubuntu Server): I have this value: `2018-05-16 20:42:36` on a record.

Calling the endpoint yields the correct JSON:

> {"timestamp":"2018-05-16T20:42:36Z"}

(the other fields were removed for sanity)

On Angular app I use:

> ... return this._http.get(this.endpoint + '/' + uuid, { headers:
>   this._getHeaders }).catch(this.handleError);

Where `<T>` represents a model that includes `timedate: Date;` as a property.

Using the service:

> this._dataService.getByUuid(uuid).subscribe(result => {
>         console.log(result);
>   });

gives:

> Object { timedate: "2018-05-16 08:05:36" }

So, the time lacks of AMPM format and I can't display it correctly. `{{element.timedate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm' }}` does nothing since `timedate` is just that, a bare string.

**What have I tried:**

- Implementing a different format in JSON output (in NancFx API)
- [Adding a HTTP INTERCEPTOR](https://gist.github.com/martinobordin/39bb1fe3400a29c1078dec00ff76bba9)
- [Reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46559268/parse-date-with-angular-4-3-httpclient?rq=1)
- Declaring the properties as Date, String

Problem is with any datetime field. The JSON is always on point and so the database.

Any help is appreciate

Answer (score 1):

JSON doesn't have a Date type (only arrays, numbers, string, object, null and undefined), so the converter from JSON to TypeScript cannot know whether it's a date or a plain string.

You need to parse (`Date.Parse(yourString)` or `new Date(yourString)`) the Date property everytime your object is deserialized.

** `Date.Parse` and the `Date` constructor can take in a Date as well as a string so you don't really have to type check the value before using them.*

Comment: That's what the interceptor does (line 37). And the output is the same.