# Safari returns incorrect value for Date toISOString()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari, mobile-safari

When I convert the date string `2019-02-16T10:00:00` into a JS Date object in timezone `GMT+0100 (CET)`, and then call `.toISOString()` I expect to get the ISO date/time `2019-12-01T09:10:10.000Z` *(-1 hour)*.

However, what I am seeing is:

**Safari** *(incorrect):*

```js
new Date('2019-12-01T10:10:10').toISOString()
// returns 2019-12-01T10:10:10.000Z
```

**Chrome** *(correct):*

```js
new Date('2019-12-01T10:10:10').toISOString()
// returns 2019-12-01T09:10:10.000Z
```

**FireFox** *(correct):*

```js
new Date('2019-12-01T10:10:10').toISOString()
// returns 2019-12-01T09:10:10.000Z
```

Am I missing something, or is this a known Safari issue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the problem. Safari is unable to convert a date string in the format `2019-12-01T10:10:10` into a `Date` object without screwing with it. The solution ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6428201/443431)) is to reformat to `2019/12/01 10:10:10` which is supported by all browsers.

```js
// convert into YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS
var dateString = '2019-12-01T10:10:10'.replace(/-/g, '/').replace('T', ' ');
```

**Safari** *(correct)*:

```js
new Date(dateString).toISOString()
// returns 2019-12-01T09:10:10.000Z
```

**Chrome** *(correct)*:

```js
new Date(dateString).toISOString()
// returns 2019-12-01T09:10:10.000Z
```

**FireFox** *(correct)*:

```js
new Date(dateString).toISOString()
// returns 2019-12-01T09:10:10.000Z
```

Hope this saves the next frustrated developer a couple of hours!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Safari takes the provided input time as the time in UTC, but Chrome and Firefox are using the local time zones. I could not find any official document supporting this behaviour. But you can easily verify it from your browser. Here are outputs for me in India `(GMT+530)`.

```
Chrome/FF:
new Date('2019-12-01T10:10:10Z').toISOString()
"2019-12-01T10:10:10.000Z"
new Date('2019-12-01T10:10:10').toISOString()
"2019-12-01T04:40:10.000Z"

Safari:
new Date('2019-12-01T10:10:10').toISOString()
"2019-12-01T10:10:10.000Z"
new Date('2019-12-01T10:10:10Z').toISOString()
"2019-12-01T10:10:10.000Z"
```