# Moment passing and saving one day before date to the server

Tags: angular, date, momentjs

I am working with the project of Angular 7. We are using matDatepicker to select a date.

When a date is selected, let's say today's date, it setting correct in angular Date object i.e.

**Date myDate**

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: {…}, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, …}
_d: Thu Jun 20 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
_i: {year: 2019, month: 5, date: 20}
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: false
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", ordinal: ƒ, _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, …}
_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -1, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
__proto__: Object
```

I know this is due to time zone, and I don't want it to save into database a day before date.

So I have converted the date as :

```
var datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
let dtStr = datePipe.transform(myDate, 'dd-MMM-yy'); -> 20-Jun-2019
```

But again I have to convert it into Date object as I have to save it to the backend, so I have tried :

```
Date convertDate = new Date(dtStr)
Thu Jun 20 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Then again it adding time zone. I want it to pass 20-Jun-2019 in Date format in the backend without a time zone as I cannot convert myDate object to a string or any other format.

How can I convert it?

Comment: Just use timezone the right way.

Comment: Your backend accepts date as `Date`? How do you pass data to the backend? as a JSON?

Comment: Yes it passed as Date (LocalDate) only.

Comment: We ended up using `moment` for handling dates. We experienced that Safari did not handle the timezone very well (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54726314/safari-returns-incorrect-value-for-date-toisostring)

Comment: @MaihanNijat it will not save as myDate object is of Date type

Comment: @NeelamSharma if you send the date in this format `20-Jun-2019` you will be saving the data in server's timezone and will be resulting difficult to convert it to local time

Comment: When passing dates around, it's best to keep the timezone info or just use timestamps. Both, as Joel said, can be converted to the user's local time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import * as moment from "moment";



let momentToDate = moment(myDate).toDate();
myDate = new Date(Date.UTC(momentToDate.getFullYear(), momentToDate.getMonth(), momentToDate.getDate(), momentToDate.getHours(), momentToDate.getMinutes(), momentToDate.getSeconds()));
```

Now myDate object is converted to UTC date and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the date without timezone in the database, using `new Date().toISOString()`.

Comment: How can I set Date myDate = new Date().toISOString(), it  error : TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.

Comment: What kind of technology are you using for backend + DB ?

Comment: We are using spring java as backend and Oracle 12c DB.