# Angular Typescript toString return an object

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I receive a client from an http get call as so:

```
    getClientById(clientId): Observable<Client>{
    let params = new HttpParams().set('clientId', clientId);
    return this.httpClient.get<Client>('http://localhost:3000/clients/getClientById', { responseType: 'json', params: params });
  }
```

My client class look like this:

```
export class Client {
name= '';
familyName = '';

public toString(){
    return this.name+ " " +  this.familyName;
}
```

}

My problem is when I call the toString() methode I receive an [object object].

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sounds like the data you get back isnt what you think it is

Comment: I assume it's a client since I can do myClient.name and it works...

Comment: Could you show us the result of your query ? Also try : let result = " "+this.name+ " " +  this.familyName; return result;

Comment: add debug line in your toString() method to display all variables

Comment: are you using the HttpClient? or are you using Http but with a different variable name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common misconception about TypeScript. In TypeScript generic types are not visible at runtime, it means you can't make magic mappings like `httpClient.get<Client>` and get a `Client` instance. 
(it is possible using AST transformers + Type-checker API, but that's another subject)

You need to manually map your object, like this :

```
getClientById(clientId): Observable<Client>{
    let params = new HttpParams().set('clientId', clientId);

    return this.httpClient
        .get('http://localhost:3000/clients/getClientById', {
            responseType: 'json',
            params: params
         })
         .map(data =>
             // build the Client instance here, data is a plain JavaScript object
             new Client(...)
         )
}
```

You get `[object Object]` because it is the default `string` value value of an `object`.

```
> ({}).toString()
"[object Object]"
> String({})
"[object Object]"
```

Comment: Thanks, I get it! Although"Observable" can't be use with "then" but I will create my Client object in the subscribed methode

Comment: doing `this.httpClient.get<Client>(...)` _is_ the map

Comment: Thats what I tought too... otherwise whats the point of creating a Client class?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon what do you mean? `data instance Client` will always be `false`, it's a plain `object`. Glad it helped @Nicolas

Comment: the `.map()` is for the angular2/4 router, the new style mapping (to a type, not a json object in general) is the `<Client>` for the httpclient

Comment: @fathyb you are mixing the old and new http methods, `.map()` isnt available on the httpClient

Comment: ths is the raw result of my query{
  "adresses": [
    {
      "adresse": "417 Boulevard Curé-Labelle",
      "ville": "Blainville",
      "code_postale": "J7C 2H4",
      "appartement": ""
    }
  ],
  "telephones": [
    {
      "noTelephone": "(555) 555-5555",
      "extention": "",
      "telephoneType": "Bureau"
    }
  ],
  "_id": "5a8dc82a3b07d204ec5e3058",
  "prenom": "Nicolas",
  "nom": "Foisy",
  "email": "nicolas@hfjdf.com",
  "sexe": "Masculin",
  "naissance": "1982-08-25T00:00:00.000Z",
  "note": "allo",
  "__v": 0
}

Comment: @fathyb please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422118/angular-httpclient-map-response (the accepted answer)

Comment: Assume that my Client class has all the requiered variables... I made it simpler for the demo on top

Comment: @NicolasFoisy are you using the httpClient? or are you using the Http with a variable name of `httpClient`?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon [`HttpClient.get`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) returns an `Observable`.
Yeah you're right sometimes (not always, even in newer versions) importing the operator is needed but it's a RxJS thing and already works for OP (probably imported whole `rxjs` somewhere). Nothing to do with Angular.

I will not go deeper in this discussion as you clearly don't look like you understand what you're talking about. You have the exact misconceptions I talked about in the anwser.

Comment: @fathyb do you even know the difference between `Http` and `HttpClient`? in terms of what/how they return data? If so, you will know that adding `<Client>` between `.get` and `(url, ...)` will map the type accordingly

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Im using the real httpClient from '@angular/common/http'

Comment: @NicolasFoisy In which case, you do not want to follow this answer as it is incorrect for the HttpClient.

Comment: Please both join me [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166972/httpclient-discussion)

Comment: Calling `httpClient.get<Client>()` just lets typescript know that the returned object will implement the `Client` interface, it does **not** mean that this returned object will be an **instance** of `Client` (so it could have similar properties, but calling any method won't work). Internally, `httpClient` just deserializes json data, it does not create and instance of any class.  So this answer is correct

Comment: @mast3rd3mon as fathyb pointed in the chat: this.clientsService.getClientById(clientId).subscribe(data =>{
      console.log(data instanceof Client); // return false

Comment: @NicolasFoisy if you wish to go against the documentation then go ahead, i'm just trying to get you to have correct code (which you already did by the way) without hte .map

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I totally understand your point and I was convicted too but as David just pointed out there is clearly no instance of client that are returned... wish is sad I agree but totaly make sense as fathyb explained in is answer.

Comment: there shouldnt be an instance returned, thats not how it works, you should map your response into an object or objects

Comment: @NicolasFoisy if you use `.subscribe(data =>{ console.log(data typeOf Client);` or `.subscribe(data =>{ console.log(data typeOf Client[]);` then you will get true, depending on if you get an array of object or a single object returned

Comment: @mast3rd3mon http://garyrafferty.com/2012/12/07/JavaScript-instanceof-vs-typeof.html

Comment: ok? i never said that it would return something that `instanceOf` would equate to true, only `typeOf` which is all it needs to do

Comment: @NicolasFoisy moreso, what does your `getClientById(id).subscribe()` look like? could you add that to the question? this might enable me to provide you with a correct answer for the httpClient which matches the docs

Comment: this.clientsService.getClientById(clientId).subscribe(client =>{ console.log(client.toString()); });

Comment: have you tried using `this.clientsService.getClientById(clientId).subscribe(client =>{ console.log(JSON.stringify(client)) });`?