# in Angular 4 HttpClient how can I receive status code?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

To get data I am doing:

```
data = this.http.get(url, httpOptions);
```

But this is only returning the body. I need the entire response to get the status. I know this syntax:

```
data = this.http.get(url, {observe: 'response'});
```

But this is replacing my `httpOpttions` which will make me unauthenticated. I can't add another argument on `GET` like I can in `POST`. Please help!

Comment: maybe this can help you, https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: @DanyParedes Thanks but I read it already. They didn't mention my case where I need to send authentication headers.

Comment: maybe duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51049806/how-to-read-the-status-from-response-in-angular-http

Comment: @rickz Not it's not. None of the answers in StackOverflow addressed the fact that HttpClieht's `http.get` would take an authentication argument also. Even the official docs don't have this case, at least to my reading so far.

Comment: Please show us how you are sending authentication.

Comment: It is like shown at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694913/angular-6-httpclient-passing-basic-auth-in-httpoptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you can't add a third parameter to your `http.get` is because it doesn't accept a third parameter. The `observe` "syntax" IS part of the `httpOptions` parameter, so all you need to do is merge what is in your `httpOptions` object with `{observe: "response"}`

For example, if your `httpOptions` looks like:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
}
```

You can combine that with the `observe` object above like this:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  observe: "response"
}
```

If you are accepting `httpOptions` as an argument (so you can't create a new one from scratch like in the previous example), you can just write the `observe` field directly on it:

```
httpOptions.observe = "response"
```

Either of these methods will preserve your current `httpOptions` object and add the `observe: "response"` field to it.

**EDIT**

For this method to work, you will need to "lie" to the compiler about `observe`'s type to allow it to compile. You can do this by adding `as any` to the end of `"response"` in your `httpOptions` object:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  observe: "response" as any
}
```

The reason this is needed is because TypeScript can't infer the type of your raw `httpOptions` object correctly (it wants `"response"` to be the literal `"body"`). Telling TypeScript to interpret `"response"` as `any` gets around this problem.

Comment: Thanks but I tried this and it didn't work. First I can't user plain object for `headers` either. It must be `headers: new HttpHeaders({
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
})`, 
and if I put `observe: "response"` underneath it like in `const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': headerAuthorization
      }),
      observe: "response"
    };`
I get a huge type error.

Comment: Interesting, you are correct. I believe it has to do with type inferencing though. It appears TypeScript can't determine that "observe" is being set to something valid, so, at least in the meantime, you can do this to have TypeScript accept it: `observe: "response" as any`

Comment: You are officially a `life saver` ;) Thank you! I never knew `as any` existed. Strange that Google never thought about `GET` with authentication and status so that we needed to lie to its compiler. Thanks again!

Comment: However, Justin, I have mention that this is still preventing me from sending my Authentication header :( Jeez!

Comment: Hmm, it shouldn't be preventing that. I mean, again you can use that `as any` idiom anywhere you are assigning a value, so if you have `httpOptions.observe = "response";` and that is giving you an error, you can do it there as well with `httpOptions.observe = "response" as any;`. But maybe I am not understanding the problem correctly, how are you doing authorization? I assumed you were passing it in as a header, which is why you have `httpOptions` in the first place. Is that correct?

Comment: OK, I made a mistake and corrected it. You're correct. The class `class LiveSaver{}` is back to you xD

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for getting the status.

**Updated on [15/02/19] :**

```js
getOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    "authToken": this.token // contains the authToken as parameter in request header 
                            // of http.get method for authorisation.
  })
};

// For getting the whole response of the request including status code etc.
getOptions['observe'] = 'response';


return this.http.get(url, getOptions)
         .pipe(
           catchError(this.handleError)
         )
         .subscribe(res => {
             console.log(res);
           },
           err => {console.log(err)} );
```

Above updated code will result in giving the whole response

Comment: Thanks but you can't do `map` here. I'm getting `TypeError: this.http.get(...).map is not a function`

Comment: import map from `rxjs` library as `import {  map } from 'rxjs/operators';
`

Comment: Dude you should be able to know that `http.get.().map()` won't use the imported `map` of `rxjs/operators`. For your `map` to work it must be a method in `http.get`. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It depends on the version of the `angular` you are using or to be specific on the version of `httpClient` you are using. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54261874/3926940) and for official docs, refer [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details)

Comment: I'm using Angular 4. None of the reference pages you mentioned answers my question. They have no authentication in the request. Thanks!

Comment: @LeeMoe, My apologies, for an incorrect understanding of the question. I have **updated** my answer according to the requirements of the question. Let me know if I have addressed your question.

Comment: Never mind, thanks for your help! I got the answer I needed from Justin.